# Help needed in understanding $2\otimes 2=1\oplus 1\oplus 2$ of $SO(2)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, trace

Vectors $\vec A=(A_1,A_2)$ and $\vec B=(B_1,B_2)$ are 2-dimensional representations of $SO(2)$. I want to understand the decomposition $$2\otimes 2=1\oplus 1\oplus 2.$$ I can easy identify that the two 1D irreducible representations are $A_iB_i=A_1B_1+A_2B_2$ and $\epsilon_{ij}A_iB_j=A_1B_2-A_2B_1$. What is the 2 on the RHS of the decomposition?

Comment: SO(2) is Abelian.  All irreps are 1-dimensional.  Do you mean O(2)?

Comment: or else are you working over the reals?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero That's a nice point. All irreps of SO(2) are 1-dimensional which would mean $2\times 2=1+1+1+1$, I guess. But Michael Seifert's and others' answers seem to prove my assertion that $2\times 2=1+1+2$. I would appreciate it if you take the pain the clarify this point.

Comment: well if you are working over the complex field then you can use $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ so the matrix $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \cos (\theta ) & -\sin (\theta ) \\
 \sin (\theta ) & \cos (\theta ) \\
\end{array}
\right)$ can be reduced to its diagonal form using a similarity transformation with complex entries.  If you are limited to the real the diagonalization cannot be done, so the field matters.  Note that O(2) has two-dimensional irreps (with basis vectors $\vert m\rangle$ and $\vert -m\rangle$ which go one into the other under the reflection in O(2)...

Comment: but this 2-dim irrep "collapses" to a 1-d irrep when $m=0$ so O(2) has both 2-d irreps (based on parity) and a 1-dim irrep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "2" is the space of all trace-free symmetric rank-2 tensors.  So an arbitrary tensor product of two vectors can be decomposed as
$$
A_i B_j = \frac{1}{2} \delta_{ij} A_k B_k + \frac{1}{2} \left( A_i B_j - B_i A_j \right) + \frac{1}{2} \left( A_i B_j + B_i A_j - \delta_{ij} A_k B_k \right)
$$
and the three "pieces" above do not mix with each other when an $SO(2)$ rotation is applied to the vectors $A_i$ and $B_i$.

Comment: The third piece should have 2 components. Am I right? If so, what are they explicitly?

Comment: @Solidification: It has two *independent* components (and hence the irreducible subspace is 2-dimensional);  but it has four components overall because it's a rank-2 tensor.  You can shown that the components of the tensor will always be of the form$$\begin{bmatrix} p & q \\ q & -p\end{bmatrix}$$ for some $p$ and $q$.

Comment: @Solidification:  Further:  if $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ have components $A_1$, $A_2$, $B_1$, and $B_2$ respectively, then the values of $p$ and $q$ above work out to be $p = A_1 B_1 - A_2 B_2$ and $q = A_1 B_2 + A_2 B_1$.

Comment: Thanks! So under a general SO(2) rotation, $p=A_1B_1-A_2B_2$ and $1=A_1B_2+A_2B_1$ will mix with each other. Is that right?

Comment: @Solidification:  Yup, that's right.  The exact mixing law is given in [@Andrew's excellent answer.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/712297/81133)

Answer (score 5):

You can parameterize a general $2\times 2$ matrix of real numbers in terms of 4 real numbers $t$, $a$, $s_1$, and $s_2$ as
\begin{equation}
A = \left(
\begin{array}
_ \frac{t}{2} + s_1 & s_2 + a \\
s_2 - a & \frac{t}{2} - s_1
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}
Note that

- The trace of $A$ is given by
  $$
  {\rm tr} A = t
  $$
- The antisymmetric part of $A$ is given by
  $$
  \frac{1}{2}\left(A-A^T\right) = \left(
  \begin{array}
  _ 0 & a \\
  -a & 0
  \end{array}
  \right)
  $$
- The traceless symmetric part of $A$ is given by
  $$
  \frac{1}{2}\left(A+A^T\right) - \frac{1}{2}{\rm tr}A \mathbb{1} = \left(
  \begin{array}
  _ s_1 & s_2 \\
  s_2 & -s_1
  \end{array}
  \right)
  $$
  where $\mathbb{1}$ is the ($2\times 2$) identity matrix.

You can check (or [have WolframAlpha check](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=simplify+matrix+multiply+%28%28cos%28theta%29%2C+-sin%28theta%29%29%2C+%28sin%28theta%29%2C+cos%28theta%29%29%29+*+%28%28t%2F2%2Bs1%2C+s2%2Ba%29%2C+%28s2-a%2C+t%2F2-s1%29%29+*+%28%28cos%28theta%29%2C+sin%28theta%29%29%2C+%28-sin%28theta%29%2C+cos%28theta%29%29%29)) that under an arbitrary rotation
\begin{equation}
A \rightarrow A' = R(\theta) A R(\theta)^T
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
R(\theta) = \left(
\begin{array}
_ \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}
that
\begin{eqnarray}
t &\rightarrow& t' = t \\
a &\rightarrow& a' = a \\
s_1 &\rightarrow& s_1' = s_1 \cos 2\theta - s_2 \sin 2\theta \\
s_2 &\rightarrow& s_2' = s_1 \sin 2\theta + s_2 \cos 2\theta
\end{eqnarray}
Since $t$ and $a$ do not change under a rotation they are *scalars* (or "1" representations). Since $s_1$ and $s_2$ get "mixed up" under rotations, they combine to form a different representation (in this case, the "2" representation).

Answer (score 3):

Any $2\times2$ matrix (4 dof) can be broken up into its trace part (1 dof), an antisymmetric part (1 dof) and a symmetric traceless part (2 dof). Hence, $2\times 2=4=1+1+2$.